# Can I start or bind to Non Exported Service from remote process of my application?

Tags: android, service, android-permissions

I have an intent service which has `android:exported="false"`, now in the same application I have another started service which runs in a separate remote process using `android:process=":remote"`. Now the question is will I be able to start that Intent service from this started service which is running in separate remote process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Non-exported services are available only to the same application and the other applications with the same UID.

Since the other applications with the same UID may run on different processes, 'living in the same process' doesn't matter.